# Mongo DB search based on multiple conditions

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am trying to search based on multiple conditions which works but the problem is that does not behave like this.

Assuming i have a search query like

`Orders.find({$or: {"status":{"$in":["open", "closed"]},"paymentStatus":{"$in":["unpaid"]}}}
)`

and i add another filter parameter like `approvalStatus` it does not leave the previously found items but rather it treats the query like an `AND` that will return an empty collection of items if one of the queries does not match.

How can i write a query that regardless of what is passed into it, it will  retain previously found items even if there is no record in one of the conditions.

like a simple OR query in sql

I hope i explained this well enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#op._S_or) here is the right approach, but its value needs to be an array of query expressions, not an object.

So your query should look something like this instead:

```js
Orders.find({$or: [
    {"status": {"$in": ["open", "closed"]}},
    {"paymentStatus": {"$in": ["unpaid"]}},
    {"approvalStatus": {"$in": ["approved"]}}
]})
```